# Develop sharepoint project without having local sharepoint installation

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint 2013 server on a remote machine.

I installed this: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585

on my development system then follow this steps.

Right click on VS 13.
Run as administrator.
File >> NEW >> Project
Templates >> SharePoint Solution
Select SharePoint 2013 - Empty Project
I got this error.

The required version of SharePoint Foundation 2013 or SharePoint Server 2013 is not installed on this system. SharePoint must be installed on the local system to develop SharePoint solutions.

Is it possible to develop SharePoint project on development system?

Comment: u can, if u only use the CSOM and no serverside api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what type of solution you want to develop. The error you get says:

> SharePoint must be installed on the local system to develop
>   SharePoint solutions.

- so you **can't** develop SharePoint solutions
- but you **can** develop apps for SharePoint.

Comment: What that means? 
Could you tell me what should I install on my computer?
I have installed Visual Studio Comunity 2017 and pack "Office/SharePoint development".

Comment: Sorry for late answer, you just need to run sharepoint installation on your development machine. The sharepoint has to run locally in order to be able to develop SharePoint solutions